# iOS Xamarin pushing a tabBar onto a navigation controller

Tags: ios, xamarin, controller, tabs, navigation

I have a login screen and once the user logs in, I want the tabs to be on the bottom and have a nav bar at the top. I can get one or the other, but not both. Is it possible?

```
    partial void LoginButton_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
            // push tab controller
            tabController = new MyTabBarController();
            navController = new UINavigationController();
            navController.PushViewController(tabController, true);
    }
```

App delegate:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, 
NSDictionary 
launchOptions)
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        // If not required for your application you can safely delete 
       this method

        //set root view controller
        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        //Create navigation controller and tab controller
        UINavigationController navctrl = new 
   UINavigationController(new 
        StartViewController());
        MyTabBarController tabController = new MyTabBarController();

        Window.RootViewController = navctrl;

        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hi , have you solved it ? If no , you can have a look at my answer . If be helpful , thanks for marking or voting up in advance *.^

Answer (score 0):

You need to first set `UINavigationController` as `RootViewController`  , then add `TabBarController` to `UINavigationController` , then it will work . As follow :

```
Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

// Set up the first View Controller
var vc1 = new UIViewController();
vc1.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;
vc1.TabBarItem.Title = "Orange";

// Set up the second View Controller
var vc2 = new UIViewController();
vc2.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Purple;
vc2.TabBarItem.Title = "Purple";

// Set up the Tab Bar Controller to have two tabs
var tabBarController = new UITabBarController();
tabBarController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] {vc1,vc2};

var registerController = new UINavigationController(tabBarController);

Window.RootViewController = registerController;
Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

By the way ,from iOS 13 you'd better write code in the method(`WillConnect`) of `SceneDelegate.cs` to set RootViewController .

```
public void WillConnect (UIScene scene, UISceneSession session, UISceneConnectionOptions connectionOptions)
{
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see UIApplicationDelegate `GetConfiguration` instead).

    UIWindowScene windowScene = new UIWindowScene(session, connectionOptions);

    // Set up the first View Controller
    var vc1 = new UIViewController();
    vc1.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;
    vc1.TabBarItem.Title = "Orange";

    // Set up the second View Controller
    var vc2 = new UIViewController();
    vc2.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Purple;
    vc2.TabBarItem.Title = "Purple";

    // Set up the Tab Bar Controller to have two tabs
    var tabBarController = new UITabBarController();
    tabBarController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] {vc1,vc2};

    var registerController = new UINavigationController(tabBarController);
    this.Window = new UIWindow(windowScene);
    this.Window.RootViewController = registerController;
    this.Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
}
```